# require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream when using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, runtime-error

I am a new user to zend framework and i tried the other solutions given in stack overflow for similar questions.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));


// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));


/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

When i echo set_include_path, this is the response i got,

**:.:/usr/lib64/php**

Do i have to install zend framework in my new Cent OS ?

My library folder is, in the same directory the index.php reside.

**/home/eat/public_html/index.php
/home/eat/public_html/library
/home/eat/public_html/library/Zend**

Update..

When i hardcoded the path as, set_include_path('/home/eat/public_html/library/');

I started getting a new error. which is,

```
    Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application.php on line 80

    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='/home/eat/public_html/library/') in /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application.php on line 80

**Update 2**

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "multidb" not found' in /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:691 Stack trace: #0 /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(626): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('multidb') #1 /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('multidb') #2 /home/eat/public_html/application/Bootstrap.php(58): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap('multidb') #3 /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(666): Bootstrap->_initApplication() #4 /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(619): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('application') #5 /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Z in /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 691
```

**Application.ini**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

eat.application.base.url = "eat.com"
eat.application.admin.url = "admin.eat.com"
eat.application.api.url = "api.eat.com"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Eat_"

resources.modules = ""

phpSettings.date.timezone = "GMT"

eat.application.salt = "sd876fs89df";
resources.view[] =
resources.view.helperPath.Eat_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Eat/View/Helper"

;;; Databases


;;;;; Layouts

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = web/web

nexva.applicaiton.fileUploadDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/../files"

;;;; ReCaptcha ;;;;
recaptcha.private_key = 6LfL7rsSAAAAAKgtKWsMk4hmA2DSVq0ODcyJFRjs
recaptcha.public_key = 6LfL7rsSAAAAANiaZOQN7LOoCGAXh29rHTZPRoVa

[staging : production]
eat.application.base.url = "eat.com"
eat.application.admin.url = "admin.eat.com"
eat.application.api.url = "api.eat.com"

;;; Databases
resources.multidb.default.adapter       = mysqli
resources.multidb.default.host          = "localhost"
resources.multidb.default.username      = "eat"
resources.multidb.default.password      = "eat"
resources.multidb.default.dbname        = "eat_main"
resources.multidb.default.default       = true

[development : production]
eat.application.base.url = "eat.com"
eat.application.admin.url = "admin.eat.com"
eat.application.api.url = "api.eat.com"

;;; Databases
resources.multidb.default.adapter       = mysqli
;resources.multidb.default.host          = "192.168.1.253"
resources.multidb.default.host            = "localhost"
resources.multidb.default.username      = "eat"
resources.multidb.default.password      = "eat"
resources.multidb.default.dbname        = "eat_main"
resources.multidb.default.default       = true

[development-alt : development]
```

**Update 3**

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function __construct($application)
    {
        parent::__construct($application);
    }

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {

        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Eat_Controller_Action_Helper');

    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
            array(
              'namespace' => '',
              'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
              'resourceTypes' => array(
                'form' => array(
                  'path' => 'forms',
                  'namespace' => 'Form',
                ),
                'model' => array(
                  'path' => 'models',
                  'namespace' => 'Model',
                ),
              )
            )
    );

    return $autoloader;
  }



  protected function _initLayoutHelper()
  {
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');

    $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Eat_Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader());

  }

  protected function _initApplication()
  {

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/application.ini", APPLICATION_ENV);
    Zend_Registry::set("config", $config);


    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

    //init DB connection
    try {

        $this->bootstrap('multidb');
        $multiDb = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');

        $db = $multiDb->getDb('default');
        $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db->getConnection();
        $db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);

        Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);

         //Just making everything UTF8. This is a hack, need to find the proper Zend way
        $db     = Zend_Registry::get('db');
        $db->query('SET NAMES "utf8"')->execute();


    } catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {

        die("Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage());

    }


  }

  public function _initRoutes()
  {
    /*
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    $router->addConfig($config, 'resources');


    $routes['featured'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'featured/:id',
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'featured', 'id' => null)
    );

    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addRoutes($routes);
    */
  }


    protected function _initLanguages()
    {


    }


    //Initilaize zend ACL
    public function _initAcl()
    {
        //Omit the process in CLI mode
        if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli')
        {
            $helper = new Eat_Controller_Action_Helper_AclDefault();
            $helper->setRoles();
            $helper->setResources();
            $helper->setPrivilages();
            $helper->setAcl();

            //Register the ACL plugin - Then it will be called automatically,whenever an acion is called
            $this->bootstrap('frontController');
            $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
       // $frontController->registerPlugin(new Eat_Plugin_Acl());


        }
    }

    //Initialize error controller
    public function _initErrorSwitcher()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new Eat_Plugin_ErrorControllerSwitcher());
    }

    protected function _initZFDebug()
    {
        //  Enabling this method seems to break autocomplete. Use only when needed
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance ();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace ( 'ZFDebug' );

        $db = Zend_Registry::get ( 'db' );

        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory ( 'Core', 'File' );

        //Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
        //APPLICATION_PATH
        $options = array ('plugins' => array ('Variables', 'Database' => array ('adapter' => $db ), 'File' => array ('basePath' => Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ()->getBaseUrl () ), 'Memory', 'Time', 'Registry', 'Cache' => array ('backend' => $cache->getBackend () ), 'Exception' ) );

        $debug = new ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug ( $options );

        $this->bootstrap ( 'frontController' );
        $frontController = $this->getResource ( 'frontController' );
        //$frontController->registerPlugin ( $debug );


    }






}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible issue would be permissions for the "library" directory.
And it affects Linux users in most cases.

If you are Linux user you may need to change them

```
sudo chmod 755 -R path_to_project/library
```

If you still experience that error then you should play around with either php.ini settings or the "library" folder location.

Answer (score 4):

your application & library folder should be located outside of public_html:

this code looks for "application" folder in parent("/../") folder (relative to index.php):

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

This code adds "/../library" to include path:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'),
  get_include_path(),
)));
```

So either move application & library folders outside of public_html, or remove /.. from the APPLICATOIN_PATH define (but this is undesirable as it will make your app less secure)

**UPD.** if you still get the error, make sure you have this file along with other Zend files:

> library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php

If not, please download latest version of Zend Framework:

ZF1:
http://downloads.zend.com/framework/1.12.10/ZendFramework-1.12.10.tar.gz

ZF2:
http://downloads.zend.com/framework/2.3.4/ZendFramework-2.3.4.tgz

You can either save it to "library" folder or unarchive it to /usr/lib64/php (so it's saved as /usr/lib64/php/Zend/), this way you won't need to have this folder for each project

**UPD2** search for

```
getResource('multidb')
```

in your code (application folder), then try to add

```
$this->bootstrap('multidb');
```

above that..

My guess is that either your Zend Framework version is different from used in original software, or your directory structure is invalid, could you try to move library&application folders outside of public_html?

**UPD3** you can also drop me an email (mstrokin at gmail.com) and I'll try to fix that for you, I love debugging :)

**UPD4** try to change "getPluginResource" to "getResource"

Comment: Now it says, Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/eat/public_html/library/Zend/Application.php on line 80

Comment: Thanks a lot. now i am getting a new error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "multidb" not found'" I updated the question as well.

Comment: I tried to search for getResoruce thingy, but i already have $this->bootstrap('multidb') in bootstrap.php. I have updated the question with my bootstrap.php code.